# When does ViewController set @IBOutlet properties?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

When does ViewController set @IBOutlet properties related to storyboard? It must be before the method viewDidLoad since I am able to print the properties without getting nil. I'm also wondering if this is related to when self.view is set.

Comment: can you share print result and your code pls ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817879/when-is-an-iboutlet-uiviewcontroller-inited-if-set-as-a-property-how-to-optimi more interesting infos https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview?language=objc `viewDidLoad` is called after `loadView`, and usually `self.view` force a `loadView`, so that's why you observed that.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the resources. So if I understand correctly, the loadView method loads storyboard files, parses them, and assigns them to the IBOutlet properties?